# HTML Input box is not triggering the events

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-events

I have the following bit of Javascript:

```
function select(id, evt) { 
        var e = (typeof evt != 'undefined') ? evt : event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        alert('err');
        var $toggler = $("#building"+id);     
        
        if(!$toggler.is(':checked')){
            $toggler.attr('checked', true);
            $("#row"+id).removeClass("selectRow");
            $("#row"+id).addClass("selectRow");            
        } 
    }
```

I have the following `<HTML>` block

```
<td>
   <select onchange="select(2, event);" name="prefferedAgent396" class="input-small">
       <option value="0">Choose...</option>
       <option value="1" selected=""> Senthil </option>                                    
       <option value="3"> Sunmeet </option>                                    
       <option value="4"> Doesnot Speak English </option>                                    
       <option value="5"> Marcus Fava </option>                                    
   </select> 
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" onchange="select(2, event);" class="input-mini" id="initial396" name="initial396" value="">
</td>
```

Now the problem is the `onchange` event triggers the `select(2, event)` for the `select` control but not the `input` control. When i tried an `alert` box where I call `select()` it worked but its not simply calling the `select()`. I have tried `onKeyUp` but it gave a strange behavior of replacing the text as I type.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd move that alert to the top of your select function, in case there's something in your cancel bubble code that's breaking.  Have you looked at what the console is reporting when you fire this event? (eg in Chrome dev tools or Firbebug etc)

Comment: No errors nothing.. I have checked the console.. and i removed the cancel bubble code as well.. No luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's *very* strange. If you rename the function from `select` to, say `select_`, it *will* work. But since you're already using jQuery, you can use the following instead of using the  inline `change` handlers:

```
$("#prefferedAgent396,#initial396").change(function (e) {
   select(2, e);
});
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vzcwq/)**.

Comment: I faced with similar problems before bu i wan't thinking this time.. thanks!!